# How i will stop this kind of warning "<object>may not response to -<function name>"

Tags: ios

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
{
classA *obj=[[classA alloc]init];

[obj show];
}
```

Here i make a object of a classA and call a function from the classA but at this point i am geting a warning that "obj may not response to -show".

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are importing everything, and have all of the frameworks you are trying to use included in your project. So in this case, you should make sure that you are importing classA, and that if it is connected to any frameworks, that they are in your project